# SQL query combining data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following query which gathers some info from 2 tables (`Students` and `Subjects`)

```
SELECT 
    'StudentName' As Student,
    'Class'   As Class,
    'Subject' As Subject
    DATEDIFF( HOUR, hoursSpent.ClassStartTime, hoursSpent.ClassEndTime ) As HoursSpent
  FROM (
        SELECT stu.StudentName from Students s

        INNER JOIN Subjects  sub
        WHERE stu.StudentId = sub.StudentId
       ) hoursSpent
```

I have another table which is exactly same as `Students` table in layout is called `OldStudents`.

My problem is I want to combine data from both `Students` and `OldStudents` and show as one but have no clue how I can do that.

I tried this but this does not work:

```
SELECT 
    'StudentName' As Student,
    'Class'   As Class,
    'Subject' As Subject
    DATEDIFF( HOUR, hoursSpent.ClassStartTime, hoursSpent.ClassEndTime ) As HoursSpent
  SELECT(
            FROM (
                SELECT stu.StudentName from Students s
                INNER JOIN Subjects  sub
                WHERE stu.StudentId = sub.StudentId
               ) hoursSpent,
          FROM (
                SELECT stu.StudentName from Students s
                INNER JOIN Subjects  sub
                WHERE stu.StudentId = sub.StudentId
               ) hoursSpent )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? What would the result set look like in relation to both tables?

Comment: @Oded - So what ever the result shows now like: StudentName, Class, Subject and HoursSpent. It be same just it will get those values from OldStudents first and then Students and populate it under one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try combining (unioning) `Students` and `OldStudents` and then joining the result to the rest of your query:

```
WITH AllStudents
AS (
  SELECT * FROM Students
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM OldStudents
)
SELECT 
    'StudentName' As Student,
    'Class'   As Class,
    'Subject' As Subject
    DATEDIFF( HOUR, hoursSpent.ClassStartTime, hoursSpent.ClassEndTime ) As HoursSpent
  FROM (
        SELECT stu.StudentName from AllStudents stu
        INNER JOIN Subjects  sub
        WHERE stu.StudentId = sub.StudentId
       ) hoursSpent
```

Comment: Awesome neat and clean exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you need to have two identical queries, one for each table and use [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms180026.aspx) (or `UNION ALL` to concatenate them:

```
SELECT 
    'StudentName' As Student,
    'Class'   As Class,
    'Subject' As Subject
    DATEDIFF( HOUR, hoursSpent.ClassStartTime, hoursSpent.ClassEndTime ) As HoursSpent
  FROM (
        SELECT stu.StudentName from Students s

        INNER JOIN Subjects  sub
        WHERE stu.StudentId = sub.StudentId
       ) hoursSpent
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'StudentName' As Student,
    'Class'   As Class,
    'Subject' As Subject
    DATEDIFF( HOUR, hoursSpent.ClassStartTime, hoursSpent.ClassEndTime ) As HoursSpent
  FROM (
        SELECT stu.StudentName from OldStudents s

        INNER JOIN Subjects  sub
        WHERE stu.StudentId = sub.StudentId
       ) hoursSpent
```

`UNION` will make the results distinct, `UNION ALL` will not.

Comment: if old students are never current students, UNION ALL should suffice.

Comment: @Syn123 - You mean `UNION`.

Comment: @Oded - So this is the best approach in this scenario?

Comment: @NoviceMe - That's what `UNION` is for. It may seem redundant, but it is the right way to go.

Comment: @Oded no I mean what I mean, no reason to use DISTINCT unless you actually need it. Here's a refresher: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add one set of data to the other use the UNION operator:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

Each SELECT statement must have the same number of columns

Comment: OOPS! That's what I meant. Thanks Jeff for catching my flub - I've corrected my answer. Red face.

Comment: But using Union wont complicate the things as there is join used by both tables? Is that the best approach?

Comment: @NoviceMe This was just a general example of `UNION`. Look at the other two answers, as they have a solution to this.  One unions the Students and OldStudents together then joins to Subjects, the other joins Students and Subjects, then joins OldStudents and Subjects, then unions them.